# Server Architecture .net/cocoa app

Tags: sql, database, windows, macos, architecture

I'm planing on creating an native .net app for Windows as well as a native OSX application with swift.

These two applications should be able to communicate with the same server. With that I mean writing and reading from the same SQL Database, and have REST communication with the server.

Now I'm struggling to come up with a solution for the backend. I'm looking into Serverless backends like Azure or Google Cloud, but I'm not sure that I can use these Services with both my applications. Both Azure and Google Cloud have SDKs for .Net but I've never found one for Swift or Objective-C.

Are there such Services that allow me to communicate or should I just develop my own?

Do you have any good solutions for my problem? Or what is the best server architecture to use for this kind of problem? Any inputs are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your servers vend a REST API, no vendor SDKs should be required.  REST is platform- and vendor-agnostic. All you need is an HTTP client, which Swift/ObjC most definitely do have. I use a serverless (AWS Lambda) setup from Swift, and it's easy. Though, I have done this kind of thing before :)

What I would do is setup a simple test server, and expose an API endpoint. Make sure you can reach it with curl from your machine. Then, take a look at the NSURLSession APIs in Foundation. They'll help you make an HTTP request similar to what curl can do. From there, you'll need to investigate serialization (like JSON), which Swift can also do easily (as of Swift 4, I believe).

Good luck!